# Getter/Setter Mongoose FeathersJS on get or find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, getter-setter, feathersjs

When using getter or setter in a mongoose schema, it is only call on create.
It's the same for a transform function in toJSON or toObject in schema options.
On a get or find there is no console.log()

```js
const schema = new Schema({
    imageId: {
      type: String,
      get: (v) => {
        console.log('Here');
        return v;
      }
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: true
    toJSON: {
      transform: (doc, ret, options) => {
        console.log('Here too');
      }
    }
    }
  });
```

Do you know how make them work on get and find ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Mongoose model properties the `lean` [service option](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose#serviceoptions) needs to be set to `false`.